# Unpermitted parameters in a simple scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models `Post` and `Photo`:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end
```

and :

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_attached_file :photo,styles:{medium:"300x300>", small:"100x100>"}
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates :photo, presence: true
end
```

I made a single change to photos_controller so photos could be uploaded, I added `:photo`:

```
def photo_params
  params.require(:photo).permit(:post_id, :photo)
end
```

But when I want to add a new photo I get this warning in log:

```
Unpermitted parameters: post
```

And here is the parameters:

```
Processing by PhotosController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gSiLdGHe3VM8Ka6gjTKk7xjcK0omPdvqfQ0DRRXdOKo=", 
"photo"=>{"post"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Update Photo", "id"=>"1"}
```

**Note**: I have a `photo` attribute in my `Photo` model but I think thats not going to make any problems and I'm using paperclip gem for uploading images.

Comment: Please post your `form code`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the parameters sent to the server, `post` (not `post_id`) is set to 1.

Rails tells you that you're trying to assign `post`, an unpermitted parameter, to 1 (while you only permitted `post_id` in your `photo_params` method).